# Is there a way to avoid typing out each variable in the return statement when using Scipys solve_ivp in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I have a code that reads in variables from excel and then solves a system of symbolic odes using solve_ivp. The code generates a list of symbolic variables ex. T = [T1, T2, T3, Tn]. It seems like I cant have return T but instead have to type out return T1, T2, T3, Tn. It defeats the purpose of having the code generate new variables based on the excel inputs. Any idea how to make this work? Im fairly new to python and this is my first post. Any advice is appreciated.

```
def dSdt(t, S):
    """ Creating ordinary differential equations """

    # T is equal to array([T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15,
           #T16, T17, T18, T19, T20], dtype=object)
           
    #T = S
    T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20 = S

    Equation_f = sym.lambdify(T, T_Final)
 
    
    return Equation_f(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20) + Q_C(t)
    #return Equation_f(T) + Q_C(t)
```

I have tried to execute whats in the commented lines as an alternative. T_Final is the symbolic equations that the T values will be put into.

```
T =  
[T1,
 T2,
 T3,
 T4,
 T5,
 T6,
 T7,
 T8,
 T9,
 T10,
 T11,
 T12,
 T13,
 T14,
 T15,
 T16,
 T17,
 T18,
 T19,
 T20]

T_Final = 
[-0.00208611481975968*T1 + 0.00208611481975968*T3,
 0.0,
 1.0e-22*T1 - 1.0e-22*T3,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0]
```

Comment: If the only reason you need separate variables `T1`, `T2` etc. is to pass them in to `Equation_f()`, then you can use the unpack operator `Equation_f(*S)`

Comment: However looking at the second code sample, it seems like you do need at least `T1` and `T3` as separate variables.

Comment: `sym` and `T_Final` and `Q_C` are all not defined.  what are they ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: T_Final is defined outside of the function. T_Final the array of ODEs that I need to solve and is made of sympy symbols. Q_C is another function that creates an array the same size as T_Final and is added at the return statement.

Comment: So *S worked!!! Only thing I need now is a way to define S without explicitly writing out T1, T2, T3, Tn = S
T already is an array of T1, T2, Tn, but it seems I cant just do T = S for some reason

Comment: Which is the start, `T` or `S`?  If `T` is an array, `T.tolist()` is a list, Aksi unpacking allows something like `T1,T2,T3,Trest*=S` (may need to check the syntax).

Comment: So T is already a list containing symbols [T1, T2, T3, Tn....]. In the function dSdt(t, S) I need T1, T2, T3, Tn.... = S but would like to do that without typing out all the variables instead of T = S

Comment: You should try to separate concerns. There is the symbolic part where you read the expressions from cells in Excel and convert this into a numerical function. And then there is the numerical part where you solve an ODE. There should be no symbolic manipulation inside the ODE function, apart from the separation issue it would make the numerical solution very slow.

Comment: So they are seperated. The equation T_Final is made outside. The problem is, T _Final has variables (potentially) T1, T2, Tn…..infinity. So when calling the function dSdt(t, S) in solve_ivp, I have to define S to be all the variables. I can do that with explicity writing out T1, T2, T3, Tn = S. I would like a way to not have to write out all the variables used for the tool can be more automatic. I have all the variables in an array called T which is made outside the function. However T=S doesn’t work